# Are there are an algorithm for to calculate a color-scheme?

Tags: algorithm

Tools like Abobe Color recommend you a set of five or six colors based upon a given color. So that you have a set of "matching" colors which looks well together.

I ask myself how this tools work.

What algorithm or formula do they use?

What are they based upon? 
Are they are any mathematical rules for calculating a "harmonic" set of colors?

Comment: My guess is that that have certain rules in place for this, and then maybe some minor alterations for making the darkness etc.

Comment: Have a look at palette.js this may help you for an algorithm https://github.com/google/palette.js/tree/master

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Obviously there have been people in the past who tried to figure out such algorithms. Algorithms like asked for. See answers. So why isn't it about programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the most popular approach is based on the colour wheel:
[image: a colour wheel]

The "analogous colours" scheme takes adjacent colours, say 315deg +/- 30 deg

The "opposing colours" scheme takes a colour and the opposing one on the wheel (+/- 180 deg)

More information here:
http://www.colormatters.com/color-and-design/basic-color-theory

Answer (score 1):

These algorithms are mostly based on a color circle. Typically, for a given hue, two other hues will be generated by moving on the color circle by the same amount in opposite directions. This means that the three resulting colors form a symmetrical triangle on the color circle.

Additional colors are then generated by keeping the hues constant and varying saturation and/or brightness of each color by the same amount.

There are also methods producing more than three different hues. These typically generate a square, pentagon, etc. on the color circle.